# How to check if a packet was dropped due to packet fragmentation?

Tags: c++, winsock

I want to write an algorithm that calculates the MTU. I'm writing all of this with functions from the WinSock2 library.

From what I understood from other posts people recommend setting the **don't fragment** bit to `true` and then sending messages with various lengths until the maximal packet size is found, but what I don't understand is:
**How to check for a dropped packet?**

E.g.:

```
/// socket has the "don't fragment" bit set.
int res = sendto(socket, dataToSend, dataToSendLen, flags /* = NULL*/, remoteAddr, remoteAddrLen);
/// How to check whether this packet has been dropped due to fragmentation?
```

Comment: Assuming you're using UDP or  raw sockets, implement a TCP-like protocol using the packet data? Sequence numbers and replies and retries is a good way to check for dropped packets and ordering problems.

Comment: Some things in life will forever remain a mystery. If your packet does not arrive at a destination within a reasonable amount of time, and if you repeat this several times, and still no dice, then this is the conclusion you will have to make. Can never be 100% certain, but which things in life are you 100% sure of, anyway?